# ShowDialog is not getting in the MDI form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Using MDI from for doing the academic project.

The problem with me is that I cant call the object of the form with `ShowDialog()` an exeption is thrown as shown below can anybody help to resolve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because the form you are calling is an mdichild of an MDI application. To get rid of error set `TopLevel` property of your Child form to `false`.

```
frm.TopLevel = false;
```

Comment: Good call, that has to be the most frustrating undocumented (at least at the time I learned of it years ago) property that needs to be set ***just*** in this situation.